# DMA Normal Mode And HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback

Tags: uart, rs485, dma

I am using UART with DMA on stm32f4xx. I am trying to use RS485 interface.
When I use the HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback, callback I get hardfault in my proccess.
How can I check transfer completed without using HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback function on stm32f4xx ?

Comment: By querying the status? The HAL manual is a good read to know how to do things. Also, how do you manage to get a hard fault, why not fix that?

Comment: Are you using DMA in normal mode? According to [this topic](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BG05R5SQJ/why-dma-complete-transfer-interrupt-wont-call-the-callback-function-haluarttxcpltcallback-) HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback won't be called in normal mode DMA. Instead you can poll for "transmit complete" bit or enable transmit complete interrupt which in turn will call HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback.

Comment: I am trying to use manual library and I am using   if( (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_TC) == SET)) function in UART2 handler but when I check the TC flag than I get same error, hard fult how can I look another flag ?

Comment: @LongPham do you know any transmit callback completed method for normal mode ?

Comment: You don't need to look at 'another flag', as there's nothing wrong with looking at the TC flag. if `__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_TC)` is resulting an a hardfault, then you're doing something wrong. Are you sure that the `huart2` struct has been initialized correctly?